# Hosting OIDC well-known config in laravel with CORS

Tags: laravel, cors, openid-connect

## Context

I'm trying to configure a laravel server as an OIDC provider. For my local machine, it works well, unless I change my origin away from one listed in my CORS policy.

## Problem

The issue is that laravel is still populating the cors headers for my OIDC well-known route, and so the client fails fetch/xhr GET requests.

## Possible solutions I have found

1. Enable CORS for all hosts - works but not the path I want to go. I value the security of having the CORS to be limited in scope.
2. Generate a static file for my well known file, and host it from the public directory. - also unideal as it makes my server less dynamic.

Is there some way I could achieve (1), but only for the well-known route? older Laravel packages allowed me to configure different profiles based on the host. What I need here, is that all hosts may access the .well-known group.

Comment: You wrote: _I value the security CORS adds._ But CORS does _not_ add security... Quite the opposite is true, actually: it relaxes some of the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: Correct... let me rephrase, I can add all origins to the CORS policy. I value the security of not including all origins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

In `config/cors.php` the paths key can accept either

1. A array of acceptable paths for all listed hosts.
2. A key value pair, with the keys as the host, and the value as an array of acceptable paths.

Thus i made a CORS policy for my frontend hosts, and a CORS policy for my OIDC routes.